# how to fetch data in wordpress and then echo?

Tags: php, wordpress, get, fetch

I am new to wordpress. I don't know about the syntax to fetch/get data from table and echo that.

plz help me.

and tell me about the syntax to fetch and echo in php with mysql.

Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `wpdb` class:

```
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, name FROM mytable" );
var_export($myrows);
```

Reference [Wordpres.org](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

```
$row = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_content name FROM bu_posts where ID='56'");
echo $row->post_content;
```

Comment: Is it SQL query? I am using mysql

Comment: yes, `"SELECT id, name FROM mytable"`

Comment: do you have a custom table? Use `foreach($myrows as $row)`

Comment: I an using this,  $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT post_content name FROM bu_posts where ID='56'" ); and what to echo?